# Python package installation error: FukuML machine learning

Tags: python

I  am installing FukuML-0.4.1 package for machine learning in anaconda python 3.5.3 in windows 10 64-bit OS. After successfully installing required dependencies such as cvxplot, pep8, I am getting following error for FukuML-0.4.1 installation. [image: error message].

```
src/C/base.c(360): error C2065: 'a': undeclared identifier
src/C/base.c(360): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping 
compilation
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files 
(x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with 
exit status 2
```

I appreciate if anyone can guide me to get the successful installation of the package. Thank you.

Comment: Don't post text as picture. Post text as text.

Comment: And also give full log, in case it is big use some pastebin service. Just showing the last error is unlikely be helpful.

Comment: Yes. Sure. I will give the full log. I am surprised to see that, even with the error message, the package is correctly working. I just check  by typing        import FukuML.PLA as pla and it worked. Any idea on this.